# How to change the default Java FX controller template in NetBeans?

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, controller

Creating a new Java FX FXML Application it makes 3 different files:

1. ${ClassName}.java
2. ${ViewName}.fxml
3. ${ViewName}Controller.java

Under the Tools/Templates menu there isn't any template option for the Controller? How can I change its default look?

[image]

Thanks,
hazazs